# How to display pagination without numbers

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables script and I don't want to see these numbers in pagination.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried, let us see the code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pagingType`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) option with `full` ('First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons) or `simple` ('Previous' and 'Next' buttons only) value to set pagination style.

For example:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
   "pagingType": "simple"
});
```

Comment: Exactly. I like easy and short answers.